# NextJS Styles weird behavior

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, components

I use NextJS.

I made reusable link component, which I can modify with new classname.

```
CustomLink.tsx:
    import { FC } from "react";
    import "./CustomLink.scss";
    import Link, { LinkProps } from "next/link";
    import classNames from "classnames";

    interface CustomLinkProps extends LinkProps {
      children: React.ReactNode;
      className?: string;
    }

    const CustomLink: FC<CustomLinkProps> = ({
      href,
      className,
      children,
    }) => {
        const finalClassName = classNames("link-button", className);

        return (
          <Link className={finalClassName} href={href}>
            {children}
          </Link>
        );
    };

export default CustomLink;
```

And when I want to modify it in other tsx file, I do it like this:

```
    import { FC } from "react";
    import "./GoHomeButton.scss";
    import CustomLink from "../CustomLink/CustomLink";

    const GoHomeButton: FC = () => {
      return (
        <CustomLink href="/" className="go-back-button">
         Go home
        </CustomLink>
      );
    };

export default GoHomeButton;
```

The problem is:

[image: in browser]

1. I have 3 of base classnames (I think it is because in other pages I used it too, and for a reason next JS does not make styles in one file)
2. My extra class in less important than base class('link-button').

I tried to make it with module.scss but get the same trouble